# Send an Email when a Duplicate Value is found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that is populated by users via a Slack form (so they don't have access to the actual sheet). The user populates a few fields in Slack and their replies and email address is added as a new row into the sheet.
I would like the script to the detect if the data in column A is a duplicate value and if so, send an email to the email address in column D from that same row.
I've found some sample scripts online for how to send an email via Google App Script, but not how to detect the duplicate value.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Don't know for sure but i dont think the script gets activated when an new form gets in. Or do you have an doPost(e) script? Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for some code. You need to dig into it yourself, show examples of what you have done and ask specific content questions. (look at: Javascript array index off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findDupRows() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const uA = [];
  const dR = [];
  vs.forEach((e, i) => {
    let idx = uA.indexOf(e);
    if (!~idx) {
      uA.push(e);
    } else {
      dR.push(i + 1);
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(dR.join(',')), 'Duplicate Rows');
}
```

Active Sheet Column1

| item1 |
| --- |
| item2 |
| item3 |
| item4 |
| item5 |
| item6 |
| item7 |
| item8 |
| item9 |
| item10 |
| item1 |
| item2 |

Results Dialog:

[image]

```
function findDupRows() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const uA = [];
  const dR = [];
  vs.forEach((e, i) => {
    let idx = uA.indexOf(e);
    if (!~idx) {
      uA.push(e);
    } else {
      dR.push(i + 1);
    }
  });
  if(dR.length>=) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(dR.join(',')), 'Duplicate Rows');
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No Duplicates Found');
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was playing around with this and noticed the dialog appears even if there are no duplicate rows. How do you set up the code to only show the dialog when there is a duplicate value?